# Open video URL in native player from Google Chrome

Tags: javascript, android, google-chrome, android-intent, video

I'm trying to open a remote video (let's say it's located at `http://www.example.com/video.mp4`) with the default Android player launched directly from Google Chrome, making use of the brand new `intent://`.

This is the URI I called through an `href` tag:

```
intent://www.example.com/video.mp4#Intent;scheme=file;action=android.intent.action.VIEW;end;
```

Of course, this URI doesn't work, and Chrome returns error "Unable to perform navigation". I've also tried the same URI omitting `scheme=file`.

Here's the documentation I've been following: https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/android/intents

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A quick browse of the Gallery App in AOSP shows that it can be launched from a browser.  [It has a category of BROWSABLE and DEFAULT](http://androidxref.com/6.0.0_r1/xref/packages/apps/Gallery/AndroidManifest.xml#115).  This means given the correct intent URL you should be able to launch it.

Obviously specifying a package should work, but that is not flexible, what if there are two gallery apps.

The following Intent scheme url works:

```
intent://www.sample-videos.com/video/mp4/720/big_buck_bunny_720p_1mb.mp4#Intent;action=android.intent.action.VIEW;scheme=http;type=video/mp4;end
```

Note:

1. scheme = http (it needs to be that or https),
2. there is a // before the domain, if that is not there the URL is not constructed correctly in the player
3. action = android.intent.action.VIEW
4. type = video/mp4 - if this is not in place the video will open in the browser

I have created a [demo that works](https://jsbin.com/puqeme/latest)

Comment: It's really nice. Working well on Android.

But I want to implement the same functionality on iOS. 
Could you take some time to help me with this?